# C# List and HtmlParse

Tags: c#, linq, list, properties

Excuse my English, its not my first language.

Class 1 is where I have my property and list
Class 2 is my html parser.

At the moment, it does its job with opening the webpage and finding the links as supposed.

Now the problem, I have, is that I want to use Linq, another List to, or what you guys think is best. 
To Sort the results by studRet(the nameid)

So all the result it found from "itsupporter" "href" is sorted by
Itsupporter
result
result

finans
result
result

How should I do this, what is best practice, any good examples which can guide me to the answer?

I have no idea how to make sure, that the links it finds is from the right studRet.

I hope this is a good enough question.

> Class1

```
private readonly List<Property> dataList = new List<Property>();
    // Get property
    internal struct Property
    {
        public readonly string url;
        public readonly string cssTag;
        public readonly string studRet;
        public readonly int id;

        public Property(string url, string cssTag, string studRet, int id)
        {

            this.url = url;
            this.cssTag = cssTag;
            this.studRet = studRet;
            this.id = id;

        }
    }

    public List<Property> GetList()
    {
        dataList.Add(new Property("http://elevplads.dk/annoncer?search=It-Supporter", "//div[@class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12']//a", "itsupporter", 1));
        dataList.Add(new Property("http://elevplads.dk/annoncer?stillingstype=finans", "//div[@class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12']//a", "finans", 2));
        return dataList;
    }
```

> Class 2

```
public readonly Jobbot Jobdata = new Jobbot();
public void HandleHtml()
    {
        List<Jobbot.Property> dataList = Jobdata.GetList();         

        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();

        foreach (var data in dataList) 
        {             
            HtmlDocument document = web.Load(data.url);
            var nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(data.cssTag);
            if (nodes != null)
            {
                foreach (HtmlNode item in nodes)
                {
                    if (item.Attributes.Contains("href"))
                    {
                        if (item.Attributes["href"].Value.StartsWith("http://"))
                        {

                            Console.WriteLine(item.Attributes["href"].Value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } // End
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand your question. You're already sending out the web request in the order you want the result set to be so I don't see why you'd need to sort them. As for mapping the links with the studRet property you could put the results into a list:

```
public void HandleHtml()

...    

List<Tuple<string, Jobbot.Property>> results = new List<Tuple<string, Jobbot.Property>>();

...

                            if (item.Attributes["href"].Value.StartsWith("http://"))
                            {
                                results.Add(Tuple.Create(item.Attributes["href"].Value, data));
                                Console.WriteLine(item.Attributes["href"].Value);
                            }
```

And then if you would really need to sort the results you could use:

```
results.OrderBy(x => x.Item2.studRet);
```

But as mentioned before, in your case it's not necessary.

Comment: I looked at it, and you're right. Thanks for making it realizing it.